# Rails: Response of Ajax JSON request got redirected. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Strangely this only happens to certain users.

```
Started POST "/search_category/autocomplete" for 172.29.11.20 at Wed Jun 12 10:51:23 -0700 2013
Processing by SearchCategoryController#autocomplete as 
Parameters: {"term"=>"a"}
Redirected to http://server.domain.com/
Completed 302 Found in 30ms
```

Server code:

```
def autocomplete
  term = params[:term].strip
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => SearchCategory.select("name, path").where('display_name  like ?', "#{term}%").to_json }
  end
end
```

Client code:

```
$("#category").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search_category/autocomplete",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data){
                var array = data.map(function(element) {
                    reverseCatMap[element['path']] = element['name'];
                    return element['path'];
                });
                response(array);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: It could be a `before_filter` that makes the redirect...

Comment: You are the man, Baldrick.  That's the cause.  I disallowed anyone but admin to access the controller. Since I am an admin, I never noticed it.